# How i can auth with jwt flask

Tags: python, jwt, ldap

tell me how to me, the token that I generated in another route:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    # initiate the form..
    form = LoginValidation()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_id = form.user_name_pid.data
        login_password = form.user_pid_Password.data
        # create a directory to hold the Logs
        login_msg = global_ldap_authentication(login_id, login_password)
        # validate the connection
        if login_msg == "Success":
            success_message = f"*** Authentication Success"
            additional_claims = {"cn": "some_audience", "name": login_id}
            access_token = create_access_token(identity='user',additional_claims=additional_claims)
            return jsonify(access_token=access_token)
            #return render_template('success.html', success_message=success_message)
        else:
            error_message = f"*** Authentication Failed - {login_msg}"
            return render_template("error.html", error_message=str(error_message))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Use to access pages:

```
@app.route('/')
@jwt_required()
def gl():
   return render_template('cd.html', results=results_flask)
```

i have error:
https://localhost:5000
{
"msg": "Missing Authorization Header"
}

Not really how to pass the jwt token to the pages if the authorization is successful at login.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use authenticated request with the returned JWT token.

Example:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1Njc0OTcyNjEsImlhdCI6MTU2NzQ5Njk2MSwibmJmIjoxNTY3NDk2OTYxLCJpZGVudGl0eSI6MX0.GncHdTHADlkeXYggn03nnmaS4tCYGNryHP6MQD7NywE" http://localhost:5000/hello
```

In the above code snippet, the JWT token is passed in Authorization header.

You can refer to [this link](https://medium.com/trabe/user-authentication-with-flask-jwt-be0e6f457dff) for complete code.

Comment: I'm a beginner, I need to insert this request in the route / somehow? @app.route('/')
@jwt_required()
def gl():curl -X GET -H "Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1Njc0OTcyNjEsImlhdCI6MTU2NzQ5Njk2MSwibmJmIjoxNTY3NDk2OTYxLCJpZGVudGl0eSI6MX0.GncHdTHADlkeXYggn03nnmaS4tCYGNryHP6MQD7NywE" http://localhost:5000/hello
   return render_template('cd.html', results=results_flask)